# How to solve this system of parameter equations with inequality conditions?

Tags: equation-solving

I have a system of three equations about pr,pn and s, while [Delta] is a parameter from 0 to 1.

```
pr -> 1/3 (2 + pn - Sqrt[(
    1 + pn + pn^2 - 2 pn s + (-1 + s) s)/(-1 + s)^2] + 
    s (-1 + Sqrt[(1 + pn + pn^2 - 2 pn s + (-1 + s) s)/(-1 + s)^2]));
pn -> 1/3 (2 - Sqrt[4 + 3 (-2 + pr) pr]);
s -> 1/6 (4 - (
    2 2^(2/3))/(4 - 27 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 + 
      3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
       pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 (-8 + 
          27 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2)])^(
    1/3) - (8 - 54 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 + 
      6 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
       pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 (-8 + 
          27 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2)])^(1/3))
&& 0 < \[Delta] < pn < pr < 1 && 0 < pr - pn < 1 - s < 1
```

I want to know the range of parameter [Delta] in which this system of equations has solution.I use Reduce to solve this problem, but it takes me a long time while can't get anything. Besides,when I try to give some real value to [Delta], I can get a solution with NSolve.
In my expressions,I made a variable substitution.

```
x = 4 - 27 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 + 
    3 Sqrt[3] Sqrt[
     pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2 (-8 + 
        27 pn (pn - pr) (-2 + pn + pr) \[Delta]^2)];
s -> 1/6 (4 - (2*2^(2/3))/x^(1/3) - (2x)^(1/3))
```

Because the s is a variable ranging 0 to 1,so I use Reduce[ 0<1/6 (4 - (2*2^(2/3))/x^(1/3) - (2x)^(1/3))<1] and get false. However, if I give [Delta] a value such as 0.1, by solving this system of equations with NSolve, I could get a solution of s between 0 and 1. I can't figure it out.

Comment: Hi there and welcome to mathematica SE.
Typically it is expected that you provide us with a code that you have attempted already so that we can copy/paste it directly on our notebooks and it should run exactly the same as on your machine. This way we can try and see exactly what or where the issue is.